# HTML Image Rows with hover over zoom

Tags: html, css, zoom-sdk

I'm trying to create an image gallery for my eCommerce website.

I am trying to code in a zoom once you hover over the images and once clicked on mobile. I have achieved this to a degree but I cannot seem to stop the images overlapping from the top and bottom of each other.

here is an example https://w3bits.com/labs/css-image-hover-zoom/ I'm trying to get all the images in the columns to zoom and be as they are in the Basic example shown on the web page.

Could anyone help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
}

.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE 10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Create two equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
  height:100%;
  -ms-flex: 50%; /* IE 10 */
  flex: 50%;
  padding: 0 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.column img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}


.column img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <img src="Vaporizers.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="Vaporizers.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="20OffBongs.jpg" style="width:70%">
    <img src="20OffBongs.jpg" style="width:70%">
    <img src="/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>  


</div>

<script>
// Get the elements with class="column"
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

// Declare a loop variable
var i;


// Two images side by side
function two() {
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.msFlex = "50%";  // IE10
    elements[i].style.flex = "50%";
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```